# How to override tpl module in prestashop?

Tags: php, overriding, prestashop, smarty

I'm working on a prestashop 1.7.4.2 project.
I purchased the storelocator module (https://addons.prestashop.com/en/international-localization/18457-store-locator-with-google-maps.html). The main template of the module does not correspond to my model.
So I overloaded the module's main template (/modules/storelocator/views/templates/front/stores_splittheme.tpl) by creating a file in the module folder of the theme of my project (/ themes / PRS175_11 / modules / storelocator / views /templates/front/stores_splittheme.tpl), then I modify to file with the desired structure.

But I have no changes to the display. I emptied the prestashop cache and the server varnish, but nothing works.

Did I forget to do a manipulation or modification?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem!
Indeed, I realized that this module already used files that moved in a subfolder of the theme.

```
public function moveFiles()
{ 
    Tools::copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'storelocator/locate/AdminStoresController.php', _PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'controllers/admin/AdminStoresController.php');
    Tools::copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'storelocator/locate/StoresController.php', _PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'controllers/front/StoresController.php');
    @Tools::copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'storelocator/views/templates/front/stores_17.tpl', _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/templates/cms/stores_17.tpl');
    @Tools::copy(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.'storelocator/views/templates/front/stores_splittheme_17.tpl', _PS_ROOT_DIR_.'/themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/templates/cms/stores_splittheme_17.tpl');
    return true;
}
```

So I only had to modify these tpl files.